# Migrating Tensorflow 1 Layers to Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm experimenting with an older piece of code that creates a very basic encoder

```
def make_encoder(data, code_size):
  x = tf.layers.flatten(data)
  x = tf.layers.dense(x, 200, tf.nn.relu)
  x = tf.layers.dense(x, 200, tf.nn.relu)
  loc = tf.layers.dense(x, code_size)
  scale = tf.layers.dense(x, code_size, tf.nn.softplus)
  return tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc, scale)
```

I'm trying to migrate this code to Tensorflow 2 due to depreciation of the tf.layer.dense, etc. I'm not very familiar with how tf.keras.layers could implement the above, but I was able to get this working:

```
def make_encoder(data, code_size):
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
  x = model(data)

  loc = model
  scale = model

  loc.add(Dense(code_size))
  scale.add(Dense(code_size, activation='softplus'))

  loc = loc(data)
  scale = scale(data)

  return tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc, scale)
```

When I run the program, I get very different/worse results compared to before. I'm certain I'm doing something wrong/am going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

It is suggested to use the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) for defining complex models, such as multi-output models, directed acyclic graphs, or models with shared layers.

Your code have to be something like this:

```
def Encoder(data, code_size):
    inputs = Input(shape=(data.shape[1:]))
    x = Flatten()(inputs)
    x = Dense(200, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(200, activation='relu')(x)
    loc = Dense(code_size)(x)
    scale = Dense(code_size, activation='softplus')(x)
    return Model(inputs=inputs,ouputs=[loc,scale])

def make_encoder(data, code_size):
    loc,scale = Encoder(data, code_size)
    return tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc, scale)
```

Comment: The error produced is a ```TypeError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'TensorShape'.``` when I reach the line ```inputs = Input(shape=(data.shape[1:],))```

Comment: Altered your code to be ```inputs = Input(shape=(data.shape[1:]))``` and it seemed to have fixed that problem. However, I now get a ```Keyword argument not understood error``` when executing the line ```posterior = make_encoder(data, code_size=2)```. Is it because I'm still running the program on Tensorflow 1, instead of Tensorflow 2 (given that the rest of the program has yet to migrate)?

Comment: I think it should run on TF1 as well. From the error you get, there may be an issue with `code_size=2`. Because the definition of `Encoder(data, code_size)` has no keyword argument. Try `posterior = make_encoder(data, 2)`

Comment: I thought that would be the fix, but I got the same error. I checked the error logs again, and I realized I forgot to inform you that `make_encoder`gets modified into a Template object during the line `make_encoder = tf.make_template('encoder', make_encoder)`. I moved the Encoder function to become a local function within `make_encoder`, and had it return `loc, scale`instead of a Model but that still produced the same error.

Comment: I am not familiar with `tf.make_template` but having a quick glance at the docs I am not sure why need it at all. I mean you achieve variable sharing by using the `Model` you have created in `Encoder` function